# How do you get the piFileType in a TFileDialog.OnTypeChange event

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to get the FileDialog's FileTypeIndex in the FileDialog OnTypeChange Event?

```
function TFileDialogEvent.OnTypeChange(const pfd: IFileDialog):
  HResult; stdcall;
var
  iCaption: string;
  iFilename: PWideChar;
begin
  {Get the current filename}
  pfd.GetFileName(iFilename);
  {Get the classname of the dialog to set the caption}
    if FClassName = 'TIEWin7FileOpenDialog' then
      iCaption := 'Open- ' + iFilename
    else
      iCaption := 'Save As- ' + iFilename;
    pfd.SetTitle(PWideChar(iCaption));
    FileTypeIndex := pfd.GetFileTypeIndex(???);
end;
```

Comment: `var FileTypeIndex: UINT; begin if Succeeded(pfd.GetFileTypeIndex(FileTypeIndex)) then {you got it} end;`.

Comment: This should be clear from the MSDN docs.

Comment: Still need the answer to the second question... I developed a new question for this.

Comment: @Bill I removed the second question from here since you've asked it in another Q.

Comment: @Bill - What is a TFileDialog?

Comment: Voted to close as there's no such thing as a `TFileDialog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation to [`IFileDialog::GetFileTypeIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775958.aspx) contains the answer. The C++ signature of that method is:

```
HRESULT GetFileTypeIndex(
  [out]  UINT *piFileType
);
```

That translates to Delphi as:

```
function GetFileTypeIndex(out FileType: UINT): HRESULT;
```

That said, the Delphi translation in `ShlObj` declares the parameter to be `var` which is semantically incorrect. As it happens it doesn't really matter.

Put it all together and you code should read like this:

```
OleCheck(pfd.GetFileTypeIndex(FileTypeIndex));
```

Note that I have added some error checking. You should too. The code in your question calls three different COM methods and in each case fails to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FileTypeIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFileSaveDialog.FileTypeIndex) property.